# extra new line added using tex4ht using BVerbatim

Tags: tex4ht, fancyvrb

This is a minor issue and I can easily work around it, but thought to mention it just in case it is not supposed to happen.

Using `\usepackage{fancyvrb}`, I needed to print lines one after
the other of same size, all verbatim. So I found I could use
`\begin{BVerbatim}` which works very well. But had to insert `\\`
after each line so that each line shows on its own line.  This
works well in PDF.  But in HTML, tex4ht create a extra empty line
between.  Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\ttfamily
\begin{BVerbatim}
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\end{BVerbatim}
\\%This is needed in PDF, else all lines show up on same line
\begin{BVerbatim}
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\end{BVerbatim}
\\
\begin{BVerbatim}
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\end{BVerbatim}
\\
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

This compiled to pdf using lualatex as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But with `make4ht foo.tex` the HTML looks like this. Extra blank line
is added.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The work around is easy. When in tex4ht mode, do not add `\\`, only
in pdf mode add `\\`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\ifdefined\HCode 
    \newcommand{\Z}{}%do not add new line for tex4ht
\else
    \newcommand{\Z}{\\} 
\fi 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\ttfamily
\begin{BVerbatim}
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\end{BVerbatim}
\Z 
\begin{BVerbatim}
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\end{BVerbatim}
\Z 
\begin{BVerbatim}
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\end{BVerbatim}
\Z
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

And now the HTML looks like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

same as PDF.

**Question is**: Is this behavior of tex4ht correct or is this a bug?

Texlive 2018 on Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave a simple blank line, instead of an explicit line break, you get the desired results without any workarounds.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\ttfamily
\begin{BVerbatim}
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\end{BVerbatim}

\begin{BVerbatim}
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\end{BVerbatim}

\begin{BVerbatim}
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
\end{BVerbatim}

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

From the `html` generated with `make4ht foo.tex`:

[image]